# Laravel query to join different tables based on a condition

Tags: mysql, laravel, join, laravel-8

How to join multiple tables based on a condition.
I have 3 tables.

- Transactions table
- advertisement table
- offerrequests table

Transaction table has relation with advertisement and offerrequests table by the fields -  is_sell and post_id

```
if is_sell = 1 then
  // post id is id in advertisement table
if is_sell is 0 then
  // post id is id in offerrequests table
```

column country is only presnt in advertisemnt and offerrequests table.
so i need to join the tables to get country for each transaction

I got the result using mysql query like :

```
SELECT transactions.id , IF( transactions.is_sell = '1', advertisements.country, offerrequests. country ) AS country 
FROM transactions 
LEFT JOIN advertisements ON ( advertisements.id = transactions.post_id )
LEFT JOIN offerrequests ON ( offerrequests.id = transactions.post_id );
```

Can anyone help me to get the laravel query corresponding to same

Comment: This would be a perfect example to use polymorphic relations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
$transactions = DB::table('transactions')
    ->select('transactions.id', DB::raw("IF(transactions.is_sell = '1', advertisements.country, offerrequests.country) as country"))
    ->leftJoin('advertisements', function ($join) {
        $join->on('advertisements.id', '=', 'transactions.post_id');
    })
    ->leftJoin('offerrequests', function ($join) {
        $join->on('offerrequests.id', '=', 'transactions.post_id');
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have one more query. if I am querying based on country how can i do that like $transactions->where('country',$request->country) is showing error like there is no column like 'country'.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I think `UNION` could be used too. Maybe it will help someone else

```
$advertisementTransactions = Transaction::select('transactions.*', 'advertisements.country')
      ->join('advertisements', 'advertisements.id', '=', 'transactions.post_id')
      ->where('is_sell', '1');

$allTransactions = Transaction::select('transactions.*', 'offerrequests.country')
      ->join('offerrequests', 'offerrequests.id', '=', 'transactions.post_id')
      ->where('is_sell', '0')
      ->union($advertisementTransactions);
```